# php wordpress get post by id and make featured section on every page

Tags: php, wordpress

I just recently code a featured section that will actually pull the post where it specify in the array. Here is the code

```
<div class="container_24">
<ul id="featured_posts" class="grid_24">

<?php $thePostIdArray = array("13968","14293", "15018", "15512"); ?>
<?php $limit = 4 ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++; ?>
<?php if ( $counter < $limit + 1 ): ?>

<?php $post_id = $thePostIdArray[$counter-1]; ?>
<?php $queried_post = get_post($post_id); ?>
 <li class="featured_post">
    <div class="featured_thumbnail"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id ); ?>"><img width="55" height="55" src="<?php echo img_feature($post_id) ?>" class="attachment-featured-small wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?>"></a></div>
    <div class="featured_title">
      <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id ); ?>"><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    </div>
  </li>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</ul>
</div>
```

Now this code working perfectly on `home`, `archive` and any page that have loop of `post` and it shows `4` featured post as it suppose to, but the problem it doesn't show on any other pages that doesn't have loop of `post` like `single.php` or `contact page` and any other that is like a single page with no post.

I don't know if I did anything wrong above I have include this on the `header` which suppose to display to all the pages that include `header` and the problem is only show the first one and not the rest is like the loop only go once and stop.

Please point me out if I did anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Well the problem here is that you loop only runs once when accessing a single.php etc because there is only one post.  I would recommend using a foreach loop instead to loop through your array of post ids.

Comment: @Jrod I'm trying to think how can I implement `foreach` in this case? really sorry I'm kinda new to php I just started the PHP course like two weeks ago

Comment: No problem.  Just posted an example.  Foreach loops are great when you are working with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreach loop like below.

```
<div class="container_24">
<ul id="featured_posts" class="grid_24">

<?php $thePostIdArray = array("13968","14293", "15018", "15512"); ?>
<?php foreach ($thePostIdArray as $post_id) : ?>
    <?php $queried_post = get_post($post_id); ?>
     <li class="featured_post">
        <div class="featured_thumbnail"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id ); ?>"><img width="55" height="55" src="<?php echo img_feature($post_id) ?>" class="attachment-featured-small wp-post-image" alt="<?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?>"></a></div>
    <div class="featured_title">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id ); ?>"><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    </div>
  </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Foreach loops were made for manipulating arrays.  Learn to love the foreach it is your friend.